# Unity 2-D installation for Linux-RedHat Fedora

Tags: linux, unity-game-engine, fedora, fedora-27

I have been trying recently to install Unity 2D on my Fedora OS. However, I could not find a unity rpm package, I found many for Debian. Unity website mainly supports Mac OS and Windows. I have run through many solutions, but none of them worked, either because they are made for an old version of Fedora or they are not completely correct. I thought of a few solutions:

- Installing Wine and trying to use the Windows version of Unity. But I do not know what are the consequences.
- Trying to run the *.deb* file on Fedora using `alien`. However, I do not know what the aftereffect will do.
- Using the Windows version on Virtual Machine, but that is the least preferred solution since it is going to consume extra RAM and processing power.

Has anyone faced such an issue and was able to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would this be helpful: http://allnightburger.com/installing-unity3d-on-fedora-24/

Comment: It is helpful. However, it is one of the solutions which are not completely correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a version for Linux but it is in the beta phase, through this URL:[Platform-Agnostic Self-Extracting Shell Script](http://beta.unity3d.com/download/fd37f3680b5f/public_download.html). It works very well indeed, I have implemented several projects containing different GameObjects and scripts. I haven't encountered any feature that exists in Windows/Mac version and I do not have it.